plotting a line graph with multiple variables on y axis against time on x axis
I am pretty new to R and I am trying to plot a line graph with time on the x axis and the different genotypes on the y axis, this is a sample of the data set that i have imported from excel into r.
The data i am trying to plot looks likes this:

 Time `Col-0` RER5     RER6 rer5rer6 Col-0 oE5 Spo…¹ Col-0…² Col-0…³ Col-0…⁴ rer6 …⁵ rer6 …⁶ rer5 …⁷ rer5 …⁸
  <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl>    <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 0.456  0.790  NA    0.817      0.230          0.739   0.808   0.811   0.805   0.791    0.282   0.193  0.734 
2 0.456  0      NA    0          0              0       0       0       0       0        0       0      0     
3 0.456  0      NA    0          0              0       0       0       0       0        0       0      0     
4 0.456  0      NA    0.00667    0              0       0.0217  0.008   0.0173  0.0333   0       0      0.0203
5 0.457  0.017  NA    0.0443     0              0.0167  0.0407  0.022   0.0397  0.0557   0       0      0.0207
6 0.457  0.0407 NA    0.075      0              0.0343  0.0757  0.0457  0.0583  0.0823   0       0      0.0413
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​`Col-0 oE5 Spot C7`, ²​`Col-0 oE5 Spot C6`, ³​`Col-0 oE6 Spot A`,
#   ⁴​`Col-0 oE6 Spot B`, ⁵​`rer6 oE6`, ⁶​`rer6 oE5`, ⁷​`rer5 oE5`, ⁸​`rer5 oE6`

However i am struggling to code in order to get R to recognise the different genotypes.
I have tried transforming the data, using the code similar to that below, but with no luck.
data_long <- pivot_longer(data, cols = -Time, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")

I have pasted the dput() output below
structure(list(Time = c(NA, 0.455532407407407, 0.456018518518519, 
0.45625, 0.456481481481481, 0.456712962962963, 0.456944444444444, 
0.457175925925926, 0.457418981481481, 0.457650462962963, 0.457881944444444, 
0.458113425925926, 0.458344907407407, 0.458576388888889, 0.45880787037037, 
0.459039351851852, 0.459270833333333, 0.459513888888889, 0.459733796296296, 
0.459965277777778, 0.460196759259259), `Y(II)` = c("Col-0", "0.79033333333333333", 
"0", "0", "0", "1.6999999999999998E-2", "4.0666666666666663E-2", 
"6.533333333333334E-2", "9.1000000000000011E-2", "0.11033333333333332", 
"0.11833333333333333", "0.14666666666666667", "0.16966666666666666", 
"0.18733333333333335", "0.20066666666666669", "0.21", "0.21333333333333335", 
"0.22266666666666668", "0.22533333333333336", "0.22833333333333336", 
"0.23099999999999998"), ...3 = c("RER5", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    ...4 = c("RER6", "0.81733333333333336", "0", "0", "6.6666666666666671E-3", 
    "4.4333333333333336E-2", "7.4999999999999997E-2", "0.12266666666666666", 
    "0.12666666666666668", "0.15833333333333333", "0.18266666666666667", 
    "0.216", "0.23666666666666666", "0.23966666666666669", "0.23199999999999998", 
    "0.25133333333333335", "0.25366666666666665", "0.25", "0.25233333333333335", 
    "0.252", "0.26166666666666666"), ...5 = c("rer5rer6", "0.22966666666666669", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4.3333333333333331E-3", 
    "5.9999999999999993E-3", "7.3333333333333332E-3", "0", "5.9999999999999993E-3", 
    "6.3333333333333332E-3", "4.6666666666666671E-3", "9.3333333333333341E-3", 
    "6.3333333333333332E-3"), ...6 = c("Col-0 oE5 Spot C7", "0.73933333333333329", 
    "0", "0", "0", "1.6666666666666666E-2", "3.4333333333333334E-2", 
    "4.1666666666666664E-2", "5.7999999999999996E-2", "6.8999999999999992E-2", 
    "7.8666666666666676E-2", "9.1666666666666674E-2", "9.3000000000000013E-2", 
    "0.10266666666666667", "0.106", "0.121", "0.13033333333333333", 
    "0.14499999999999999", "0.14933333333333335", "0.16966666666666666", 
    "0.16700000000000001"), ...7 = c("Col-0 oE5 Spot C6", "0.80766666666666664", 
    "0", "0", "2.1666666666666667E-2", "4.066666666666667E-2", 
    "7.5666666666666674E-2", "9.7666666666666679E-2", "0.12233333333333334", 
    "0.15966666666666665", "0.16733333333333333", "0.18600000000000003", 
    "0.18733333333333335", "0.19466666666666665", "0.18800000000000003", 
    "0.18666666666666668", "0.20033333333333334", "0.19899999999999998", 
    "0.20499999999999999", "0.21233333333333335", "0.20933333333333329"
    ), ...8 = c("Col-0 oE6 Spot A", "0.81066666666666665", "0", 
    "0", "8.0000000000000002E-3", "2.2000000000000002E-2", "4.5666666666666668E-2", 
    "7.1000000000000008E-2", "8.8666666666666671E-2", "0.10633333333333334", 
    "0.12966666666666668", "0.14966666666666667", "0.16266666666666665", 
    "0.18466666666666667", "0.19033333333333333", "0.18100000000000002", 
    "0.18166666666666667", "0.17966666666666667", "0.17900000000000002", 
    "0.19166666666666665", "0.20166666666666666"), ...9 = c("Col-0 oE6 Spot B", 
    "0.80466666666666675", "0", "0", "1.7333333333333333E-2", 
    "3.9666666666666663E-2", "5.8333333333333327E-2", "8.9333333333333334E-2", 
    "0.11633333333333333", "0.14033333333333334", "0.158", "0.18133333333333335", 
    "0.19099999999999998", "0.20599999999999999", "0.20966666666666667", 
    "0.21466666666666667", "0.21166666666666667", "0.216", "0.21466666666666667", 
    "0.21566666666666667", "0.21433333333333335"), ...10 = c("rer6 oE6", 
    "0.79066666666666663", "0", "0", "3.3333333333333333E-2", 
    "5.566666666666667E-2", "8.2333333333333328E-2", "0.10099999999999999", 
    "0.12366666666666669", "0.14033333333333334", "0.16300000000000001", 
    "0.17266666666666666", "0.18533333333333335", "0.19099999999999998", 
    "0.19366666666666665", "0.19699999999999998", "0.20833333333333334", 
    "0.21833333333333335", "0.21866666666666665", "0.23366666666666669", 
    "0.23066666666666666"), ...11 = c("rer6 oE5", "0.28199999999999997", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...12 = c("rer5 oE5", 
    "0.19299999999999998", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "5.0000000000000001E-3", "0", "0", "0", 
    "1.2666666666666666E-2", "0", "0", "0"), ...13 = c("rer5 oE6", 
    "0.73366666666666669", "0", "0", "2.0333333333333332E-2", 
    "2.0666666666666667E-2", "4.1333333333333333E-2", "4.9666666666666665E-2", 
    "6.2333333333333331E-2", "7.1333333333333346E-2", "7.9666666666666663E-2", 
    "0.10033333333333333", "9.9000000000000019E-2", "0.10766666666666667", 
    "0.109", "0.11599999999999999", "0.121", "0.12", "0.12833333333333333", 
    "0.14000000000000001", "0.13766666666666669")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L))

Any help would be much appreciated.

You're on the right track. Please paste the output of dput(yourdata), or a subset of such  as dput(yourdata)[1:20] so that we may help further. Once the data are in long format I'm assuming you wish to use ggplot? Update with that information as well (would you prefer to work in ggplot, or in base R?).

Please add your sample data to your question as the output from dput(data). That will make it easier for us to help you.

I have pasted the dput() output into the question and yes I am planning on using ggplot. Thanks

Based on the data you have provided, it appears your column names are in the first row. I fixed that issue and then provided a start to some basic ggplot code for you. From there you should be able to add to the ggplot code to achieve your desired result.
library(tidyverse)
colnames(data) <- data[1,] # Fix column names
names(data)[1] <- 'Time'   # Some error in your dput, fix Time column name
data <- data[2:nrow(data),]# Remove column names row


datalong <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Time) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% # remove missing values
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) # convert values to numeric


# all on one panel 
ggplot(datalong,
       aes(x = Time, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()


# faceted 
ggplot(datalong,
       aes(x = Time, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~name)



For what I understand from you question, this can be done in the following way
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(your_data, aes(x = time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = genotype1, color = "Genotype 1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = genotype2, color = "Genotype 2")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Genotype 1" = "red", "Genotype 2" = "blue")) +
  labs(color = "Genotype")  # Optional: Add a legend title



And like this for your different genotypes.
